# Interpreter result type not found despite importing it

Tags: scala, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

I use Scala 2.9.1. I have a simple scala "interpreter":

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Results.Result
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Results.Success

object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val interpreter = new IMain
    val result:Result = interpreter.interpret(args(0))
    result.toString() match {
      case "Success" =>
        {
          var success = result.asInstanceOf[Success]
          println(success.productElement(0))
        };
      case _ => println("very bad result");
    }
  }

}
```

When i try to compile it (maven) i get:

```
[ERROR] /home/koziolek/workspace/dsi/src/main/scala/pl/koziolekweb/scala/dsi/App.scala:15: error: not found: type Success
[INFO]           var success = result.asInstanceOf[Success]
```

As you can see, the compiler said that there is no type Success, although I imported it.

Comment: For a test, can you import the Success in the line just before `var success = results.asInstanceOf[Success]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Success` is an object, not a class, you would need to cast it to its singleton type `result.asInstanceOf[Success.type]`. Obviously you are trying to work around not knowing how to do the pattern match. That would allow you to get the right result without casting:

```
import tools.nsc.interpreter.Results._

result match {
   case Success    => "yes!"
   case Error      => "no..."
   case Incomplete => "you missed something"
}
```

If you want to get the *resulting value of the interpreted expression* in the case of success, see [my reply in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807207/how-to-check-errors-happening-inside-scala-interpreter-programatically) for more details.